How to install Etcher on Ubuntu 24.04 when booted on a PC from a flash drive?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on a PC, with Ubuntu booting off a USB drive. I cannot get Etcher to open. I have an App image; I set it to Run as a Program. It won't open. I saw another solution posted here, but it requires rebooting, which I cannot do.

Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1511655/124466. The temporary solution does not require rebooting.

This question is similar to: How to make Balena Etcher and other appimages work in Ubuntu 24.04?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
